# Condition with Join or Where Clause in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I want to understand how hive executes both the queries. Do we have any Query optimizers in Hive ?

```
select * from A JOIN B on A.a = B.b 

select * from A JOIN B where A.a = B.b
```

Please let me know how Hive query is getting executed (Workflow)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it appears that Hive doesn't do any good backend optimization here.  I wrote myself a couple of examples and compared the stage plans and abstract syntax trees.

```
select * from A JOIN B on A.a = B.b
```

In the above query, hive finds where A.a = B.b and then joins the two together.

```
select * from A JOIN B where A.a = B.b
```

In this query, hive joins A to B on every value - hive performs a cross join, which is a massive mapping stage (assuming your tables are large).  Then during the reduce stage, hive filters out the rows where A.a != B.b

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Charlie Haley. Can you please let me the way to get the stage plans and abstract syntax trees ?

Comment: If the tables A and B are already in hive, just type explain (insert query here);

Comment: If you can explain, please let me know what is the query execution flow in hive ?